# Spring Boot Pojo of Pojo validation not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two Pojo in my spring boot application

Pojo 1: FeedData

Code(i have the get and set, just didn't show it here):

```
package com.cms.tb.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class FeedData implements Serializable{

    @JsonProperty("feed_id")
    private int feedId;

    @JsonProperty("feed_category_id")
    private int feedCategoryId;

    @JsonProperty("feed_data_json")
    private FeedDataJson feedDataJson;

    @JsonProperty("user_profile")
    private UserProfile userProfile;


}
```

..in the above pojo, there is another Pojo called FeedDataJson which has validations.

Code 2: FeedDataJson Pojo

```
package com.cms.tb.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class FeedDataJson {

    @NotBlank(message = "feed_title is Mandatory")
    @Size(min = 4, max = 25, message 
    = "feed_title must be between 4 and 25 characters")
    @JsonProperty("feed_title")
    private String feedTitle;

    @NotBlank(message = "feed_body is Mandatory")
    @Size(min = 4, max = 2000, message 
    = "feed_body must be between 10 and 2000 characters")
    @JsonProperty("feed_body")
    private String feedBody;

    @JsonProperty("feed_meta_tags")
    private List<String> feedMetaTags;
}
```

whenever i send a request via POSTMAN, there validations are not happening in FeedDataJson Pojo.

sample request data:

```
{
    "feed_data_json":{
        "feed_title":"",
        "feed_body":"LOL",
        "feed_meta_tags":["m1"]
    },
    "feed_category_id":1,
    "user_profile":{
        "user_id":1
    }
}
```

**This should throw an Validation Error, because feed_title is empty,right?**

my Controller code:

```
@PostMapping(path="/v1/createfeed")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createFeedController(@Valid @RequestBody FeedData requestData)
            throws TBFeedException, TBFeedDBException, JsonProcessingException {

        // Create ObjectMapper
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        String feedDataJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(requestData.getFeedDataJson());
        FeedData newFeedInfo = ITBFeedDAO.createFeed(requestData,feedDataJson);
        newFeedInfo.setFeedDataJson(requestData.getFeedDataJson());

        JsonNode dataNode = mapper.valueToTree(newFeedInfo);

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(generateResponse(dataNode), setHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Try annotating the `feedDataJson` property with `@Valid`. (And eliminate `Serializable`; it's rarely used in modern Java applications.)

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- isn't required? so my pojo can run without having convert it into serilizable object?

Comment: `Serializable` is specifically for built-in Java serialization, which has been mostly replaced with JSON/XML, Avro, or Protobuf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @Valid on `feedDataJson` propertry in `FeedData` class.

```
@Valid
private FeedDataJson feedDataJson;
```

For nested property, you need to use @Valid also.